# Wordpress Instead of showing search result. show category entry right away (with acf map)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi the code below is for my search page and its working properly and it will show the search item along with **the map marker** what im trying to do now is show all post from the category example "category1", "category2" how can i do that? thank you so much

```
<div id="posts_cont">
        <?php
        while ($search_query->have_posts()) : $search_query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID ();
            $location = get_field_object('gmap', $post_id)['value'];
            $title = get_the_title($post_id);
            $url = get_permalink($post_id);
            $comments = get_comments(array('post_id' => $post_id));
            //$ratings = rating_form();
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
            $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail', true);
            $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];



            if( !empty($location) ):
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(".acf-map").append("<div class='marker' data-lat='<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>' data-lng='<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>' title='<?php echo the_title_attribute(); ?>' ></div>");

            </script>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php if (!have_posts() || $search_query->post_count == 0) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#search-title").hide();
            $(".acf-map").hide();
            $(".search-text").hide();
            $(".container").append("<h6 class='title'>Oops! No results were found.</h6>");
        </script>

        <?php } ?>
```